# Issues connecting Web3js to local testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js-v1.x

I am trying to connect web3 to a testnet running locally. I am using the following code

```
    var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");

    var account = '0x742d35Cc6634C0532925a3b844Bc454e4438f44e';
    web3.eth.getBalance(account, (err, bal) => {balance = bal});
    console.log(balance);
```

But I get the folowing error in the browser window:

```
    web3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
        at n.sendAsync (web3.min.js:1)
        at l.t [as getBalance] (web3.min.js:1)
        at index.html:41
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is your web3 version?

Comment: I am using version 1

Comment: if you are connecting to ganache, you could use httpProvider instead.

Comment: this issue is pointed out and a workaround is suggested here https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57#issuecomment-379877709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by downgrading to web3 v 0.2.6